# What would the layout/rooms be like in an African style royal palace?

Tags: architecture

I'm writing a fantasy novel with one of the main characters being part of the royal family of an African-style country. I'd like to describe their palace, as well as its various rooms (not just what they'd look like but various names also, for example - Great Hall, Reading Room) but I'm finding it really difficult to find anything on palaces specifically, especially ones that were built by Africans themselves and not colonisers. Does anybody know where I could find this info, or could give me some answers please?

Some more details below:

- The palace would have been built in our equivalent of the 15th century, with the story being set in the mid 1800s.
- The country's main religion is based around their gods sitting in the stars, so they place heavy emphasis on being able to see the sky. I thought about putting their palace on the foothills of a mountain, with the rest of the city sprawled below - would this work for other reasons?
- There are magic users in this world, known as witches; other countries view these people as tools, soldiers, slaves, but this country believes they are descendants from gods, so they are treated with reverence. Several top advisors to the Queen are magic users.
- The country is fairly peaceful and has had a long period of relative calm -- possibly due to the number of witches they have in high positions at their disposal?

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Africa is a whole continent, it cannot have a single style. That apart, if you are looking for historical examples of some well defined regions in Africa, you might have better luck in History.SE

Comment: Good point! Thank you :)

Comment: this the one i know off from [mali](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/84/c0/ce/84c0ce2f9fb20dc6832a1102c529729e.jpg) but i dont know the interior or the native name for the rooms, beside the interior already redesign into mosque, but it doesnt much different from plain european castle as far as i can found, so dont expect any ornament or color in it. outside of that, maybe try check egypt architecture? they are considered as african right?

Comment: Hi @cobaltblue, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Questions about aesthetics are often closed as too opinion-based because there's rarely an objective best-answer. Please note that (a) African history is filled with all kinds of immigration, so what's an "African" to you? (b) [There are many examples of castles on the African continent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_castles_in_Africa), but the further back you go, the more medieval they become. (c) The predominant religion for most of those castles, I suspect, was Islam.

Comment: What have you researched already? This is a basic google question. I think you should research native African kingdoms, and there are many; and then look at their royal residences. I'd personally look at Ethiopia, as I think it ticks most of your boxes, especially the long period of relative calm. It wasn't until the 1970s that the barbarous commies overthrew the Emperor. You can't get much more African-style than Ethiopia!! You can even find video of HSM Haile Selassie's coronation on Youtube.

Comment: @LiJun: That photograph is of the [Great Mosque of Djenné](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Mosque_of_Djenné), built by the French in 1906. It looks like a muddy imitation of a European palace because it is.

Comment: *"The royal family of an African-style country":* There is no such thing as an "African-style country". There is a great desert in Africa, which divides the continent into two very distinct parts, inhabited by very different peoples. North Africa is inhabited by Europoid people, and it was always fully integrated with the European and western Asian culture and civilization; it is fully a part of the classical world. Sub-saharan Africa is very large and very diverse. Central Africa, western Africa, eastern Africa and southern Africa are different, their people and cultures are all different.

Comment: As has been said, it depends which part of Africa you're thinking of. We don't have much information about Great Zimbabwe, for example, but you might could find decent documentation of the royal palace of Kumasi, or the downright epic palace at the heart of Benin City. And Ethiopia has the advantage of having not been blown up during Colonization. Given your setting, I lean toward Benin City / Edo for references (you have immense fortifications and bronzeworks that could double as lightning-rods, and that's before you get inside...).

Comment: Some good images of "forgotten African architecture" from various cultures on [this thread](https://twitter.com/AllanCudicio/status/1168137757828497408)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the concept of a palace in the way we understand it was a case in many African countries. Yet you might find this [TED Talk about fractal villages](https://www.ted.com/talks/ron_eglash_the_fractals_at_the_heart_of_african_designs) interesting though. It might not be a representative selection of all African areas but shows for instance that this is a recurring idea, even though implemented in various ways in different regions of Africa, apparently independently. It is also not complete information, but it offers a starting point. Finally, the surprising relation to mathematics can add to the story. You can consider building upon it and imagine how a palace build following the same principles might look like.